# Code Golf: C#: Convert ulong to Hex String

Tags: c#, hex

I tried writing an extension method to take in a ulong and return a string that represents the provided value in hexadecimal format with no leading zeros.  I wasn't really happy with what I came up with... is there not a better way to do this using standard .NET libraries?

```
public static string ToHexString(this ulong ouid)
{
    string temp = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(ouid).Reverse().ToArray()).Replace("-", "");

    while (temp.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
    {
        temp = temp.Substring(1);
    }

    return "0x" + temp;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution is actually really simple, instead of using all kinds of quirks to format a number into hex you can dig down into the [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) class.

The solution to your problem is as follows...

```
return string.Format("0x{0:X}", temp);
```

Though I wouldn't make an extension method for this use.

Comment: Beat me to it :o)  Also, found this.  Similar question:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d14da7dc-6258-42a1-b660-d18bdf9635b8

Comment: Haha, awesome.  return "0x" + ouid.ToString("x").ToUpper();  <3

Comment: I'll actually be helpfull...so you can skip all the BitConverter, etc.

return string.Format("0x{0:x}", temp);

If you even wanna write an extension for that purpose (which i wouldn't) :D

Comment: No need for the ToUpper()...just us X instead of x matey :)

Comment: @Ardman, it's funny... in all my google searching I never actually searched for "ulong to hex", I kept typing UInt64 in all my searches.   Google needs synonym searches.

Comment: May I suggest having a look at NumberFormatInfo just like CultureInfo, those two classes are often overlooked by people cause they tend to think there is no help for that kindda stuff :)

Comment: @Langdon - google HAS synonym searches http://www.googleguide.com/synonym_operator.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use string.format:

```
string.Format("0x{0:X4}",200);
```

Check *[String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)* for a more comprehensive "how-to" on formatting output.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 6 you can use string interpolation:

`$"0x{variable:X}"`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated